# Where to do the collision detection

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

this is a question I've had for a while but never bothered asking.

Imagine I have 2 objects. 1 static, and the other movable (by player).

*Where would the collision logic exist for that?*

To elaborate; in my state I have a list of **Components**. These can be NPCs, static objects, the player, and just about everything being

```
private List<Component> _gameComponents;
```

If I were to do the check in the **Player** class, surely the player would need to know of the **_gameComponents** list, and then I'll do the check as I update so I can change the velocity accordingly.

Is there a standard I'm missing?

**EDIT 1:** I have just read that I should have a step between update and render for checking all collision. I'll give that a try, and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Let every component that can be physically processed inherit from a custom `interface` like `ICollidable`.

Store every `ICollidable` in a `List<T>` that is separate from your components-list. And every `ICollidable` that is not static in even a third collection.

Have a third class that just processes the whole physics-part of your game and iterates through the non-statics-list. This way you only update what can be moved and you can compare it to every object that is in the list that contains every `ICollidable`.

Make sure you only check collision for objectes that are within the range of a moving object. It makes no sense to check a collision for an object that won't collide.

I always check for collisions before update, try what works best for you.